# JSON in C#: How do I get all objects in a json string below a certain class?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization, json-serialization

I am trying to get everything below apps  and put the values inside a `Dictionary<string, Games>`

I am using the below code.

Class:

```
public class Games
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Code:

```
public Dictionary<string, Games>   GetAllGames()
        {
            //http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?key=STEAMKEY&format=json

            var url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?key=STEAMKEY&format=json";

            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(url));

            WebReq.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

            string jsonString;
            using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var t = JObject.Parse(jsonString).SelectToken("applist").ToString();
            var  s = JObject.Parse(t).SelectToken("apps").ToString();

            Dictionary<string, Games> gamesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Games>>(s);



            return gamesList;            

        }
```

Error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,LudumPricer.Games]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

JSON sample:

```
{
   "applist":{
      "apps":[
         {
            "appid":5,
            "name":"Dedicated Server"
         },
         {
            "appid":7,
            "name":"Steam Client"
         },
         {
            "appid":8,
            "name":"winui2"
         },
         {
            "appid":10,
            "name":"Counter-Strike"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to get everything under the `apps` attribute and put them in a `Dictionary <string, Games>`

I am using the newtonsoft json.net library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert and use `ToDictionary`

**Given**

```
public class App
{
    public int appid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Applist
{
    public List<App> apps { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Applist applist { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
var dict = root.applist.apps.ToDictionary(x => x.appid, x => x.name);
```

---

[Enumerable.ToDictionary Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a Dictionary from an IEnumerable according to
>   a specified key selector function.

Comment: Nice! Worked like a charm. Thanks!